# How can I expand the touchable area of a UICollectionViewCell beyond its bounds?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, multi-touch

I have a collection view cell with a label that extends outside of the cell's bounds. The cell doesn't clip the label. I would like the didSelectItemAtIndexPath to detect a selection if the user taps on the part of the label that extends beyond the cell's bounds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Touchability of subviews does not normally extend outside the bounds of the superview. You will therefore need to munge the hit-testing for your collection view cell class, so that its subviews are touchable even if the touch is outside the bounds of the cell.

In my book, I give an [example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch05p210hitTesting/ch18p551hitTesting/ViewController.swift) (which you can download and try out on your machine) that works like this:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, with:e) {
        return result
    }
    for sub in self.subviews.reversed() {
        let pt = self.convert(point, to:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, with:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

You might need to adapt that somewhat, though, because it may be that the label is not a direct subview of the cell (as assumed in that example code). However, it does show the idea.

Comment: For the theory and practice involved here, see the earlier edition of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and override `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` to return `true` if the point is inside the cell's label:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let pointInLabelCoords = convertPoint(point, toView: label)
    if label.pointInside(pointInLabelCoords, withEvent: event) {
        return true
    }
    return super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
}
```

Or if you need a more robust solution that allows touches on any out-of-bounds subviews, just enumerate `contentView.subviews` and ask each view if the point is inside.

Bear in mind that this approach will only work if the cell (including its touchable out-of-bounds subviews) are wholly contained in the cell's superview. This is because of the way the view hierarchy is traversed when the system looks for a view to respond to the touch (see `hitTest(_:withEvent:)`). If the touchable area will sit outside the cell's superview's bounds, you will also need to override `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` on *that* view (the collection view) as well.